# Software for very simple editing of advanced .psd files

Tags: software-rec, image-editor

I need a Linux application for very simple editing of advanced `.psd` files in Linux. Turning on and off layers would be enough. Unfortunately, GIMP has way too many problems with it. It is unable to display image with few more advanced layers correctly. It renders little different picture. Is there any other solutions other than Photoshop in Wine?

P.S.
I'm fine with GIMP interface and I don't know Photoshop. However it looks I have to work with `.psd` files.

Comment: is your problem with "Photoshop in Wine" Photoshop (don't want to pay) or wine?  if it's the first, try [xnView on wine](http://my.opera.com/area42/blog/2006/12/22/viewing-psd-photoshop-files-on-linux-w)

Comment: It looks there is xnView for Linux. However, it isn't powerful enough. Well, if there was an official Photoshop for Linux, I would buy it. Probably. The many kinds of DRM, few very Windows hacks and so on aren't vary stable in Wine. I don't want to pay for something that may fail.

Comment: What's *problems* does GIMP have?

Comment: The GIMP doesn't render some images correctly.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually need is software for light editing of advanced `psd` files. That's a different problem.

Comment: Actually, Caleb, "advanced" is probably overstating it. I just tried to open a trivial 2-layer composite I made in Photoshop in The Gimp, and it got it wrong. I checked, and the most advanced feature of Photoshop I used to create it was introduced in Photoshop 6.0, released 11 years ago. (It dropped the "blend if" layer style.) Michas, sometimes you just need Photoshop. There are no complete substitutes.

Answer (score 5):

*The GIMP* is definitely the go-to image editor on Linux. It has the best `psd` support of any native editor or viewer. You say "it has too many problems" but you don't explain what any of those are. It is quite stable, actively keeps up with the latest developments in the OS and implements bug fixes in a timely manner. Since you seem willing to consider *Photoshop* and even things that run in *Wine*, complexity and size don't seem to be your concern.

Allow me to suggest that *The GIMP* can probably be customized for your purposes. The default interface can be configured to show very little besides the image window and one toolbar (say with just the pan and zoom tools) which can have the layers dbx attached for simple viewing operations.

The most likely thing that comes to mind is that you might consider a "problem" is how different it is from *Photoshop*. It does approach things from a little bit different angle. If these are your problem you could consider some of the config file / plugin combinations that make some of it's behavior more recognizable, although I actually suggest you will be better off in the long run learning a little bout how it works for it's own sake.

If you more explicitly state what problems you see in it, you might get help fixing those. This is likely to be less work, more stable, and better integrated with the rest of your Linux environment than a foreign piece of software under *Wine*.

Comment: The best way to put it.

Comment: I don't have any problems with interface. The GIMP is just unable to render correctly some images.